# CSV file generation issue on IE9

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, csv, pdo

I'm looking at an odd issue with Internet Explorer 9. The below code successfully generates a populated CSV file when ran in Safari, IE8, IE10, IE11, Chrome and Firefox but generates an empty CSV file (Headers only) in IE9. It does not appear to be a data issue considering the bug only appears to happen in IE9. I've been able to test and confirm on 3 different machines running IE9.

It's a legacy script I inherited with SQLSRV instead of MSSQL PDO, though I took the liberty of scooping out mysql and replacing it with PDO and wrapping it in a function and thoroughly commenting it for my own sanity.

```
        # Create a CSV sheet with details we need
    # Generate file name based on timestamp
    $file = "$_SESSION[user_name]_" . "tutorincomplete_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-sa");

    # 1: Open CSV File 
    $myFile = ".\csv\\" . "$file.csv"; 
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 

    # Get list of active classes from MSSQL DB
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 
    static_title, 
    LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, course_end_date, 120), 150) AS course_end_date, 
    RTRIM(static_code) as static_code, 
    RTRIM(session_code) as session_code,
    staff_name
    FROM 
    snip";

        # Append to query where a school is present
        if (ISSET($_SESSION['user_school']) AND $_SESSION['user_school'] != "None")
        {
        $sql .= "
        WHERE
        school = ?
        ORDER BY staff_name ASC";   
        $params1 = array($_SESSION['user_school']);
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params1);
        }
        else
        {
        if (isset($_POST['school']) AND $_POST['school'] != "All") {
        $sql .= "
        WHERE
        school = ?
        ORDER BY staff_name ASC";   
        $params1 = array($_POST['school']);
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params1);
        } else {
        $sql .= "
        ORDER BY staff_name ASC";   
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
        }

        }

        $today = date('U'); 

        # Set headers for CSV file
        $head = array("Static title", "Course end date", "Static code", "Session code", "Staff name");
        fputcsv($fh, $head);
        $count = 0;

            # Loop through MSSQL results for comparison
            while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {

                $finish = $obj['course_end_date'];
                # Strip the time (keep ISO date format intact)
                $finishSub = substr($finish, 0, 10);

                # Create timestamp from date format
                $finishTs = strtotime($finishSub);

                # Compare and display <option> tag if valid
                if ($today > ($finishTs - 604800))
                {

                    # Fetch information on course; Decide of course is complete or incomplete
                    # To do this, first check for course entries in the MySQL database
                    # If they are present, we will use MySQL instead of MSSQL (To reference completed courses)
                    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM snip WHERE static = :stc AND session = :sec ORDER BY static ASC";
                    $query3 = $pdo->prepare($sql3);
                    $query3->bindParam(':stc', $obj['static_code']);
                    $query3->bindParam(':sec', $obj['session_code']);
                    $query3->execute();
                    $rowCount = $query3->rowCount();


                    # Check for result count in MySQL
                    if ($rowCount > 0)
                    {
                    $result = $query3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                        if ($result->complete == 0) {
                        $incomplete = 1;
                        } else {
                        $incomplete = 0;
                        $count++;
                        }

                    } else {
                        # No MySQL entry; Mark as incomplete
                        $incomplete = 1;
                    }

                        if ($incomplete > 0)
                        {
                        $arr = array($obj['static_title'], $obj['course_end_date'], $obj['static_code'], $obj['session_code'], $obj['staff_name']);
                        fputcsv($fh, $arr);
                        }

                }

            }

    echo "
    <h1>CSV file generation complete</h1>
    <p>Skipped $count classes</p>
    <p>File generation complete. File name $file.csv <a href=\"./csv/$file.csv\">Click here to open</a></p>";
    }
```

In anything but IE9, it generates "Skipped X classes", CSV file has x number of entries.

But in IE9, "Skipped 0 classes", CSV file only contains column headers.

EDIT: I found out through some experimentation that SQLSRV is passing an empty array *ONLY* in IE9. It's not affecting any other browser. As such I was able to impress upon the powers that be that I need to switch the system to PDO for MSSQL. Guess I can call this fixed but unresolved.

Comment: If I were you I wouldnt just upgrade the driver since it was a working legacy  script ...

Comment: Waiting on IT to roll out an IE update to the affected user (Most are on IE10) but I'd rather resolve the issue for any ongoing support.

Comment: I am actually surprised you get it to work on some browser, it is not very recommended to mix `sqlsrv_` and `PDO` extensions in the same script

Comment: I've never heard that before. Plus I didn't bring in `SQLSRV`, only the `PDO` since my genius predecessor was dropping GET and POST variables straight into a MySQL query

Comment: How does a `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_SESSION)` in IE9 compare with the same from other browsers?

Comment: Session is fine - it's a quite extensive system that uses granular database permissions set with session variables for various sections of the system. No issues there at all. POST data is only used for slimming down the report and comes across fine - in this case, "CB"

Comment: The script executes on the server side. So it shouldn't make a difference what browser you're using, unless it's not passing the proper data to the script. So the only thing you need to check is any data that is passed into this script, which appears to be `$_SESSION` and `$_POST`. I know you've said that they look fine, but....perhaps take another look, really closely?

Comment: They're passing the correct data as per `var_dump`. Inserting breakpoints shows the script breaks down on the `while($obj...)` part of the query despite `SESSION` and `POST` being identical cross browser. I've switched to PDO now regardless. Just an odd, odd problem. I was told not to waste time on it but turns out some important people were using it.